# run ios app Example( by java language) at jailbreak device

Tags: java, ios, jailbreak, cydia

I have an itouch4, ios 6.1.6 and jailbreak.
I just want to run opera-mini-4.22.jar on my itouch4.
So, I do some search work to find a way. I run it successed at Android platform used by Microemu project at first, and I found a directory named "microemu-iphone" in the microemu project, So I created a deb file and installed my itouch4. But it does not work, I got some error message when I run `/Applications/MicroEmulator.app/MicroEmulator` in a terminal.
The message below:

> objc_getClass("UIHardware")
>   source/joc/Runtime.m(657): _assert(2:false)

After that I found some other apps used by java, there are
HelloJava, HelloScript and JavaSysInfo.
All of them have same problem is just to show a titlebar with white content area and disappeared after 2 seconds when I click the app icon.
When I run command at terminal it threw some error message.
For example like HelloJava:

```
cd /Applications/HelloJava.app/
./HelloJava
```

error message is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native
>   library `uicaboodle' not found (as file`libuicaboodle') in
>   gnu.classpath.boot.library.path and java.library.path    at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:763)    at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:671)    at
>   com.saurik.uicaboodle.Main.(Main.java:13)

So I add some command to HelloJava file

```
 -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/classpath
```

run it again and no any error message show up.
But HelloJava app still does not work like before when I click app icon.

I got some log from itouch4 real time log

> Jun 23 10:16:11 Gaby-iPod-touch com.apple.launchd[1](http://opera-mini.ru/file/opera-mini-4.22.jar)
>   (UIKitApplication:com.saurik.HelloJava[0xf1fc][3246]) :
>   (UIKitApplication:com.saurik.HelloJava[0xf1fc]) Exited with code: 1
>   Jun 23 10:16:11 Gaby-iPod-touch com.apple.launchd[1](http://opera-mini.ru/file/opera-mini-4.22.jar)
>   (UIKitApplication:com.saurik.HelloJava[0xf1fc]) :
>   (UIKitApplication:com.saurik.HelloJava[0xf1fc]) Throttling respawn:
>   Will start in 2147483647 seconds
>   Jun 23 10:16:11 Gaby-iPod-touch
>   backboardd[2998] : Application
>   'UIKitApplication:com.saurik.HelloJava[0xf1fc]' exited abnormally with
>   exit status 1

I also mail to author of HelloJava app saurik@saurik.com, but didn't respond.
Now make these examples working is the first job, if example working, maybe MicroEmulator app will working too.
I really appreciate your help if you have a jailbreak ios device, and install HelloJava app to test it is working or not.

All the packages I installed is: Classpath(0.99-4), iPhone/Java(1.0.2474-2), JamVM(1.5.2-4), Java SQLite(20080130-3), JocStrap(1.0.2549), UICaboodle(1.0.2475-2)

After that I have no idea how to make it work, hope anyone can help me.
Thanks a lot.

All the resource links can found below
 1. [opera-mini-4.22.jar](http://opera-mini.ru/file/opera-mini-4.22.jar)
 2. [Microemu](http://microemu.blogspot.com/)
 3. HelloJava, HelloScript: apptapp.saurik.com/com/saurik/
 4. [JavaSysInfo](http://iphoneroot.com/javasysinfo-another-sample-gui-java-application/)

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, I highly doubt that even if you solve this related problem you will get anywhere on this. OperaMini for mobile devices requires all sorts of other libraries and oddities that iOS won't be able to provide. If you get this to ever work, please make a blog post but I think you're better off putting your time somewhere else. Who knows, maybe someone will find a jquery library that'll do this for you.

Comment: All the apps base jocStrap and UICaboodle package, I think if HellpJava app work, maybe MicroEmulator app will work too.